Make Circular barplot customization in R
I saw the example on here https://r-graph-gallery.com/ which is really good but now I am stucked.
I tried to create a circular barplot with groups using the country data with different groups Am, As, E, Af.
As I post the plot, I want to display the name of countries instead of Individual.
data=data.frame(
    individual=paste( "Individual", seq(1,60), sep=""),
    group=c( rep('America', 10), rep('Asia', 30), rep('C', 14), rep('D', 6)) ,
    value=sample( seq(10,100), 60, replace=T)
)
data = data %>% arrange(group, value)

# Set a number of 'empty bar' to add at the end of each group
empty_bar=3
to_add = data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group), ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) = colnames(data)
to_add$group=rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar)
data=rbind(data, to_add)
data=data %>% arrange(group)
data$id=seq(1, nrow(data))

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data=data
number_of_bar=nrow(label_data)
angle= 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data=data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data = base_data
grid_data$end = grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start = grid_data$start - 1
grid_data=grid_data[-1,]

# Make the plot
p = ggplot(global, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) +       # Note that id is a factor. If x is numeric, there is some space between the first bar
    
    geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
    
    # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
    geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 80, xend = start, yend = 80), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
    geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 60, xend = start, yend = 60), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
    geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 40, xend = start, yend = 40), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
    geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 20, xend = start, yend = 20), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
    
    # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
    annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),4), y = c(20, 40, 60, 80), label = c("20", "40", "60", "80") , color="grey", size=3 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
    
    geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
    ylim(-100,120) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        legend.position = "none",
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
    ) +
    coord_polar() + 
    geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=value+10, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2.5, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
    
    # Add base line information
    geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  +
    geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)
p```

Data used [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hxZROTPoSb8bmVrdpvZsYzbSjjkuCzBw/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110428553292471673820&rtpof=true&sd=true][1] 


You need to add + coord_polar() or + coord_radial() to make it circular. That's an important line in the code you linked but haven't included in your own plot.

The posted code does not work, the plot is not created with a call to ggplot(). Also, images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See this Meta and a relevant xkcd. Can you post sample data in dput format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of dput(data). Or, if the data set is too big with the output of dput(head(data, 20)).

used data and code updated!

The code here works, you just have to change
p = ggplot(global, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) + 

to
p = ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=group)) + 

grid_data, used in the geom_segment, is derived from data at this point.
